VBA filtering data for multiple keywords
I want to filter data based on keywords which can be more than 2. I found below solution on this website which seems to be working fine for 2 or if the criteria are 4  and above. However this code does not work when their are 3 keywords. It then only takes the last keyword and gives output. I also want to add one more filter criteria of range (which would be numerical e.g , between 3 to 12) this would change based on requirements. My data is between column A:L. I am filtering keyword on column L and want range filter on column J. My data has header so I change offset to 0 in below code.
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFilteredData()
    
    Const lName As String = "Report Generator"
    Const lrgAddress As String = "C4:C7"
    
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const sCols As String = "A:F"
    Const sfField As Long = 5
    
    Const dName As String = "Report"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Const doCopyHeaders As Boolean = True ' e.g. if dFirst = "A2" then 'False'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the criterias to a dictionary.
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(lrgAddress)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim lString As String
    
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        lString = CStr(lCell.Value)
        If Len(lString) > 0 Then
            dict("*" & lString & "*") = Empty
        End If
    Next lCell
    
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = dict.Count
    If dCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no criterias
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Source Table Range
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(sCols)
    ' Source Data Range ('strg' without headers)
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    Select Case dCount
    
    Case Is < 3 ' up to two criteria with wild characters
        
        strg.AutoFilter sfField, dict.Keys, xlFilterValues
        Set srg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    Case Else ' more criteria with wild characters
        
        Dim fpCount As Long: fpCount = Int(dCount / 2)
        Dim UB As Long: UB = 1
        Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(0 To 1)
        
        Dim sfdrg As Range
        Dim fp As Long
        Dim n As Long
        
        ' For each filter pair...
        For fp = 0 To fpCount
            If fp = fpCount Then ' last loop only
                If dCount Mod 2 = 1 Then ' count is odd: needs to loop once more
                    UB = 0
                    ReDim arr(0 To 0)
                Else ' count is even: no need to loop anymore
                    UB = -1
                End If
            End If
            If UB > -1 Then
                ' Write criteria pair to an array.
                For n = 0 To UB
                    arr(n) = dict.Keys()(n + fp * 2)
                Next n
                ' Filter Source Data Range.
                sdrg.AutoFilter sfField, arr, xlFilterValues
                ' Combine filtered range into Source Range.
                On Error Resume Next
                Set sfdrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
                sws.AutoFilterMode = False
                If Not sfdrg Is Nothing Then
                    If srg Is Nothing Then
                        Set srg = sfdrg
                    Else
                        Set srg = Union(srg, sfdrg)
                    End If
                    Set sfdrg = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next fp
        
    End Select
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If doCopyHeaders Then
        Set srg = Union(strg.Rows(1), srg)
    End If
    Debug.Print srg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Copy to the Destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    dws.Cells.Clear
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
End Sub 

An error is thrown if the search string has 3 keywords.

I think your problem is here: `Select Case dCount
Case Is < 3 ' up to two criteria with wild characters`

You posted the same code as in the original answer. You can download the file that I used to develop it here if that is of any help. I tested it and it works for 3 criteria. So it would be more useful to post the code you're using so we can compare it to the original. Maybe there is a minor mistake that could be easily fixed. Also, post a sample of your sheets as text so we have something to work with.
